# How to get a key of an object that was pushed just now in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create kind of registration without password and email. I use only nickname. So,I have a User class that has nickname field and other fields. So, I want to push new user and the thing that I want is to save its key because I will need it in the future when I have to get some user's data. So how can I get a key of an object that was already pushed?

Here is my code how I push:

```
User user = new User() ;
user.setNick(nick.getText().toString());
user.setScore(0);


Firebase fire = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.URL) ;
//how to get key of this object? Is it possible before pushing? 
fire.push().setValue(user);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the key, please use the code below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.push();
String key = keyRef.getKey();
keyRef.setValue(user);
```

or

```
Firebase fire = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.URL) ;
String pushKey = fire.push().getKey();
fire.child(pushKey).setValue(user);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But where I have to push my User object?

Comment: On `keyRef`reference.

Comment: It seems working,but it generates for me two keys. Inside the first key is another one and inside this is my user object . Is it ok? How can I avoid that? I'll accept answer soon

Comment: To avoid this, you need to use the `push()` method only once. So you will have only one key,

Comment: `DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootRef.push().setValue(user);
        String key = rootRef.getKey();
        Log.d("key", key);`   Why key is null here?

Comment: Error was `The println needs a message` .  But I fixed it adding " " to key. But key is null. Why?

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Try the second approach.

Comment: Error here . You are setting void to Firebase object.

Comment: Ignore the second solution. The first one must run. Can you please addd here a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks.Worked this one: `Firebase firebase = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.URL);
        Firebase fire = firebase.push() ;
        String key = fire.getKey() ;
        fire.setValue(user);
        Log.d("imp",key.toString()) ;`

Comment: You copy pasted my answer =.=

Comment: Jus modified mine. Take a look at my previous versions.

Comment: That's rude u know =.=. Nvm, happy to help though.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get pushKey before you do `push()`.

You can try this one instead.

```
Firebase fire = new Firebase(FirebaseConfig.URL) ;
String pushKey = fire.push().getKey();
fire.child(pushKey).setValue(user);
```