# Updating data in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update the above record but when I update that it updates the parent (user) instead of the child.

```
  `     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendNotification();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String ID=intent.getStringExtra("counter");
            String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
            m.put("ID",ID);
            m.put("Email", email);
            if(s!="Query" && s!="Resource")
            m.put("Complain", t.getText().toString());
            else if(s!="Complain" && s!="Resource")
            m.put("Query", t.getText().toString());
            else
            m.put("Resources",t.getText().toString());
            m.put("Time", "");
            m.put("Feedback", "Pending");
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").updateChildren(m).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Your data is successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });`
```

DB structure:
[image: DB structure]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update the above record but when I update that it updates the parent (user) node instead of the child.

That's the expected behavior since your calling `updateChildren()` on the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
```

Which points exactly to the `User` node. If you want to update the child, you have to add the key to the reference:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference childRef = db.child("User").child("-N2gd...8-6b"); 
childRef.updateChildren(m).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

So the key to solving this problem is to add the key of the node in your reference. If you didn't store the key yet, then please check the answer from the following post:

- [How to get a key of an object that was pushed just now in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199583/how-to-get-a-key-of-an-object-that-was-pushed-just-now-in-firebase)

Comment: `DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.push();
                String key = keyRef.getKey();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "key : "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference childRef = db.child("User").child(key);
                childRef.updateChildren(m); `                    I write this code but faces same problem

Comment: You should **not** create a new key, you use the existing one (`"-N2gd...8-6b"`). The example provided in the last link works only when you add new data. Add that ID inside the reference and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes I works if we put key manually. But what if we want to update any specific key at run time? How is it possible. Please tell me about this

Comment: Simply by knowing the ID before reading the child. That's why I showed you that example, right?

Comment: Hey Fatima. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I am thankful, tell me if possible

Comment: I was asking if I can help you with other information regarding this question, right?

Comment: Yes I understand this. Guide me with other information .

Comment: So what remains unresolved about this issue?

Comment: I have some how solved update issue and then I am trying now to retrieve data. I have retrieved all data from database but unable to retrieve data on the basis of specific attribute like pending feedbacks in my project

Comment: Have you tried to perform a query based on the `pending` property?

Comment: No . I don't try this .Please guide

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer/comments and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Hey Fatima, can I help you with other information regarding the **initial** question?